# Is it possible to add custom fonts on windows phone 8 on web browser control using css

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is it possible to support custom fonts on windows phone 8 html5 apps using web browsers control with css and html. If possible tell me how to do that.

Thnaks
Dinesh

Answer (score 0):

look you already get the solution. But someone keep finding the solution, here is my answer:

(1). Create the CSS with embedded font

```
body, a, p, span, div, textarea {
        font-family: MyCustomFont;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: MyCustomFont;
    src: url(data:application/x-font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,d09GRgABAXXXXXXXXXXX......) format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

(2.) Inject jQuery and CSS at WebView_NavigationCompleted method

```
 private async void MyWebView_NavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
 {
    // Inject jQuery file which located at local
    StorageFile jquery = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///JavaScripts\\jquery-1.10.2.min.js"));
        string jquery_string = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(jquery);
        await MyWebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { jquery_string });


    // Inject custom font embedded CSS 
    StorageFile myfontcss = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///CSS\\mycustomfont.css"));
            string myfontcss_string = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(myfontcss);

            myfontcss_string = myfontcss_string.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\t", ""); //.Replace("'", "&#39;").Replace("\"", "&#34;");
            string cssRef = "$(\"<style id='myfont' type='text/css'>" + myfontcss_string + "</style>\").appendTo('head');";

            await MyWebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { cssRef });

 }
```